# Binary operator '+' can not be applied to two 'int2' operands. Need to use '&+'

Tags: swift, simd

I am trying to convert some code from Objective-C to Swift and running into this situation:

```
import simd

let a = int2(1, 0)
let b = int2(0, 1)

print(a + b) // COMPILER FAILS
print(a &+ b) // SUCCESS
```

Why is the purpose of changing a perfectly understandable syntax to this cryptic notation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the Xcode 7 Release notes about Swift 2:

> SIMD improvements: Integer vector types in the simd module now only
>   support unchecked arithmetic with wraparound semantics using the &+, &-,
>   and &* operators, in order to better support the machine model for
>   vectors. The +, -, and * operators are unavailable on integer vectors,
>   and Xcode automatically suggests replacing them with the wrapping 
>   operators.

(from https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/xc7_release_notes.html)

The unusual syntax is specifically there to make it obvious that the addition is being done with unchecked arithmetic.

Comment: Great, thank you for your reply. I wasn't aware about all the efforts that went into dealing with integer overflow in Swift. Really interesting stuff about detecting overflow and casting values to lesser bit size types. Thanks!

Comment: also, you can improve the performance :[Advice: Use unchecked integer arithmetic when you can prove that overflow cannot occur](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/OptimizationTips.rst#advice-use-unchecked-integer-arithmetic-when-you-can-prove-that-overflow-cannot-occur)

Answer (score 1):

Take out your Swift book and find the difference between a + b and a &+ b for plain integers.

Now you are using vectors. There is no SIMD operation that has the same semantics as +. It could be built, but then you would complain how slow it is. There is however a SIMD operation that has the same semantics as &+.